Dirichlet problem of $f$-Laplacian equation of vector fields on a compact Riemannian manifold
On a compact $n$-Riemannian manifold with boundary $(M,g)$, $f$ is a smooth function on $M$. Consider the $f$-Laplacian operator $\Delta_f$ acting on vector fields defined by
$$\Delta_f V=\Delta V-\nabla_{\nabla f}V,\forall V\in\mathfrak{X}(M)$$
and the Dirichlet problem
$$\Delta_f V=Q\quad in\;M,$$
$$V=0\quad on\;\partial{M}.$$
I want to know the existence and uniqueness of this Dirichlet problem.
My idea is to write this equation in local harmonic coordinates $(U,(x^i)),$ which means
$$0=\Delta x^i=g^{jk}(\partial_j\partial_k-\Gamma_{jk}^l\partial_l)x^i=-g^{jk}\Gamma_{jk}^i.$$
Here is my calculation:
$$\Delta_fV=g^{ij}(\partial_i\partial_jV^s+\partial_jV^k\Gamma_{ik}^s+\partial_i(V^k\Gamma_{jk}^s)+V^k\Gamma_{jk}^t\Gamma_{it}^s-\partial_jf\partial_iV^s-V^k\Gamma_{ik}^s)\partial_s.$$
Then if $U\cap\partial{M}=\emptyset,$ then we have the following elliptic partial differential equations of second order:
$$g^{ij}(\partial_i\partial_jV^s+\partial_jV^k\Gamma_{ik}^s+\partial_i(V^k\Gamma_{jk}^s)+V^k\Gamma_{jk}^t\Gamma_{it}^s-\partial_jf\partial_iV^s-V^k\Gamma_{ik}^s)=Q^s\quad in\; U$$
And if $U\cap \partial{M}\neq\emptyset$, then the zero boundary condition will appear.
Now I have a question: Does this second order elliptic partial differential equation have a unique solution? Because I found I only know existence and uniqueness of a elliptic equation of second order with non-positive coefficient of the zero order term. But for the above equation, the zero order term does not vanish. How can I tackle this?
I think there are some standard references concerning elliptic equations on compact Riemannian manifolds but I don not find a good one. Any suggestions will be appreciated!
